# Route attribute routing with query strings when there are multiple routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Cats")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByCatId(int catId)

[HttpGet]
[Route("Cats")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByName(string name)
```

They are called by providing the query string eg `Cats?catId=5`

However MVC Web API will say you can't have multiple routes that are the same (both routes are "Cats".

How can I get this to work so MVC Web API will recognize them as separate routes? Is there something I can put into the Route property? It says that `?` is an invalid character to put into a route.

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge the two actions in question into one

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Cats")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCats(int? catId = null, string name = null) {

    if(catId.HasValue) return GetByCatId(catId.Value);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return GetByName(name);

    return GetAllCats();
}

private IHttpActionResult GetAllCats() { ... }

private IHttpActionResult GetByCatId(int catId) { ... }    

private IHttpActionResult GetByName(string name) { ... }
```

Or for more flexibility try route constraints

Referencing [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 : Route Constraints](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints)

> **Route Constraints**
>
> Route constraints let you restrict how the parameters in the route
>   template are matched. The general syntax is "{parameter:constraint}".
>   For example:
>
> ```
> [Route("users/{id:int}"]
> public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }
>
> [Route("users/{name}"]
> public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
> ```
>
> Here, the first route will only be selected if the "id" segment of the
>   URI is an integer. Otherwise, the second route will be chosen.

Comment: This method means `users/5` works but not `/users?name=5` which is what I need

Comment: In that case you would have to merge those two methods into one and perform the action based on the populated parameter.

Comment: otherwise you need to differentiate the two actions more so that there is not a conflict in route mapping

Comment: @NibblyPig, check updated answer and see if that works for you

Comment: Have tried this, it doesn't distinguish between names so if you have two routes, one takes `string catId` and one takes `string catName` you get an error `Multiple actions were found that match the request` if you go to `theUrl?catId=CAT75` or `theUrl?catName=Jeff. If I use a single route with both parameters it doesn't work nicely with swagger/swashbuckle or other stuff like logging :(

Comment: @NibblyPig Then you need to review your routes as there are conflicts. show your route configuration.

Comment: @NibblyPig attribute routing allow for more flexibility with specific routing requirements while convention-based routed as the name implies follows a convention. Trying to mix the two is difficult when the routes a similar. attribute routing works best when the parameters are segments of the url not in the query string.

Comment: also based on you last comment it means that the question was incomplete as nothing was mentioned about `swagger/swashbuckle or other stuff like logging`

Answer (score 4):

Try applying constraints on attribute routing.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Cats/{catId:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByCatId(int catId)

[HttpGet]
[Route("Cats/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetByName(string name)
```

Comment: it is string by default. no need to put it just put `{name}`